# Is there any APIs to control desktop's power supply(turn on/off, sleep mode)?

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-desktop

I have a plan to develop Flutter Desktop & mobile App.
My demand is ‘How to control desktop's power supply.’
For instance, when I press the application's button
the desktop turns off/on, or goes to sleep mode.

Is there any APIs on the Flutter Desktop satisfying me? Plz help me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve this result by using the flutter Process class.

Basically what you want to do is run a command based on the users platform to shutdown or sleep the user's desktop. for an example if you run following command in your windows cmd it will shutdown your pc.

```
shutdown -s
```

and in linux you can use following command to shutdown the desktop

```
sudo shutdown -n now
```

in theory running the particular commands based the platform from dart process class you can turn off a pc of the user.

for an example to shutdown a windows pc you can use `Process.run` as following

```
   print("Shutting Down!");
   var cleanProcess = await Process.run('shutdown', ["-s"]);
```

Please refer following documentation for more information

[Flutter Process Class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Process-class.html)

[Linux shutdown commands](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-shutdown-command/)

[Windows shutdown commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)